# AWS EFS Backup using Datapipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I want to take backup of my EFS production environment.
I have setup solution as defined in walk through
[efsbackup walkthrough.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-backup.html) with 2 EFS file system: Production & Backup

I created 4 security groups :

1. efs-mt-sg (EFS SG) & add access to efs-ec2-sg on NFS port.
2. efs-ec2-sg(EC2 SG).
3. efs-backup-mt-sg (backup EFS SG) & add access
   to efs-ec2-backup-sg on NFS port.
4. efs-ec2-backup-sg(backup EC2
   SG).

I have setup data pipline using template [1-Node-EFSBackupPipeline.json](https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/blob/master/samples/EFSBackup/1-Node-EFSBackupPipeline.json)

Now when I activate this pipeline it runs well with status Finished and shows me logs as in Stdout with all command executed, but i don't see any backup in my backup EFS when i mount in ec2 and check size of same comapring with production EFS.
Where as, when I add an EC2 instance using security groups efs-ec2-sg,efs-ec2-backup-sg and run all specified commands in [efs-backup.sh](https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/blob/master/samples/EFSBackup/efs-backup.sh) it works well and i can see this EFS file system with backup files. How can i get this data pipeline work through?

Comment: When I run command manually on EC2 Instance it takes time to execute as there is 15GB of data where as data pipeline runs this in few seconds, not sure what is wrong. Any help!

Answer (score 2):

So this is precisely the problem I had when I first setup this backup system back in Dec '16.. Turns out the base ami that datapipeline spins up to execute the backups isn't properly configured with the nfs tools needed. So it attempts to mount but fails and subsequently just trots along as if everything is ok.. Define the AMI in your pipeline - check the latest jsons in github, and plug in the latest AMI for your region - easily found with a google search, you should be good to go.

Or you can just edit your pipeline and add the ImageId attribute with value to your various EC2Resources...